# Create "update all" state in Saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

Hello helpful friends,

We have quite a setup here of 100+ servers being managed by Salt states. With different roles in the organization executed by different people, I'd really like to have a possibility to "aggregate" some states. In this case: updating (yum) packages.

I would really like to have our sysadmins safely being able to execute a command like this on the master:

```
salt '*' state.apply update.packages
```

while maybe our developers would be able to execute:

```
salt 'dev-*' state.apply update.application
```

Of course we have a large set of sls files and the key to this issue is that I don't want all those states executed, but just a selected bunch of them.

To achieve this, I've tried to create an `update/packages.sls` state, containing:

```
update-packages:
  test.nop
```

And then added to, for example the following existing state:

```
nagios-plugins-all:
  pkg.latest:
    - require:
      - pkg: corepackages
```

a `watch_in` as follows:

```
nagios-plugins-all:
  pkg.latest:
    - require:
      - pkg: corepackages
    - watch_in:
      - test: update-packages
```

Unfortunately, this is clearly not the way to go, as executing `salt 'testserver001' state.apply update.packages` now only returns:

```
testserver001:
    ----------
    test_|-update-packages_|-update-packages_|-nop:
        ----------
        __id__:
            update-packages
        __run_num__:
            0
        changes:
            ----------
        comment:
            Success!
        duration:
            0.946
        name:
            update-packages
        result:
            True
        start_time:
            12:10:46.035686
```

while I know for sure that updated packages are available. I can't `include` all the existing state files into the `update/packages.sls` file, as that would cause **all** states to be executed in those files and that's not what I want either. It would also become a very messy file.

I also don't want to just execute `salt '*' pkg.upgrade` as I have states depending on updates; i.e. if the package `nagios` is updated, the states concerning the up-to-date config files should be run and consequently a restart of the `nagios` service should be executed. All of that is configured in salt using `watch` and `require` arguments, so I'd like to use that also when updating my packages. Also, I want to be in control of which packages can be updated.

I don't know if I'm on the right path, or whether this is possible with Salt at all, but maybe someone here has a brilliant idea on how to achieve this behavior. I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [External Auth System](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/eauth/index.html) of salt.

This way you can limit users and group to specific minions and commands, and even restrict the parameters.

Comment: I do not want to restrict users in actually being able to execute stuff, I want to make it easier to execute repetitive tasks that consist of multiple states in different directories...